Angular Render Component using NgComponentOutlet with dynamic content projection
    <mat-button-toggle-group appearance="legacy"    [(ngModel)]="selectedClockType">
        <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item" color="primary">
           {{ item.label }}
        </mat-button-toggle>  
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
       
     @for (item of items; track:item.id) {   
          <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="item .component"></ng-container> 
        }

     <ng-template #actionItesm let-data="data">{{data}} </ng-template>

component-a.html
    <ng-content></ng-content>

component-b.html
<ng-content></ng-content>

Am Trying to pass ngTemplate by using  below code
 <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="item .component;content: actionItesm ></ng-container> 

and  using  inside all the components that am using inside Items

If you're using angular material anyway, you might as well use the CDK ComponentPortal or TemplatePortal

Yes this could be one of the alternative, any way its not my project, am just trying to explore Angular as newbie or else could have tried this

You need to use the createEmbeddedView of ViewContainerRef where we input the template as a first argument, followed by a second argument containing the template context. I have created a new property templateRef which contains the created template ref structure. Then finally we pass that input to the property content of *ngComponentOutlet
The example mentioned in NgComponentOutlet is a great example for understanding the steps and process.
FULL CODE:
PARENT TS:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef,
  TemplateRef,
  Injector,
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { AComponent } from 'src/app/a/a.component';
import { BComponent } from 'src/app/b/b.component';

/**
 * @title Basic button-toggles
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'button-toggle-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-toggle-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    CommonModule,
    AComponent,
    BComponent,
    FormsModule,
  ],
})
export class ButtonToggleOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild('actionItesm', { static: true }) actionItesm!: TemplateRef<any>;
  selectedClockType: any;
  items: Array<any> = [
    { id: 1, label: 'a', component: AComponent },
    { id: 2, label: 'b', component: BComponent },
  ];
  myContent?: any[][];
  myInjector: Injector;

  constructor(injector: Injector, private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.myInjector = injector;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Create the projectable content from the templates
    if (this.items?.length) {
      this.items.forEach((item: any) => {
        item.templateRef = [
          this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.actionItesm, { item: item })
            .rootNodes,
        ];
      });
    }
  }
}

PARENT HTML:
<mat-button-toggle-group appearance="legacy" [(ngModel)]="selectedClockType">
  <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item" color="primary">
    {{ item.label }}
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
<br />
<br />
<br />
@for (item of items; track item.id;) { {{item.label}}
<ng-container
  *ngComponentOutlet="item.component;
  content: item.templateRef;"
></ng-container>
}
<ng-template #actionItesm let-item="item">{{item.label}} asdf</ng-template>

CHILD TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  styleUrl: './b.component.scss'
})
export class BComponent {

}

CHILD HTML:
<br />
<hr />
B COMPONENT
<ng-content></ng-content>
<hr />
<br />

Stackblitz Demo

Yes, i have seen this example by Angular.io do we have to realy loop in since we are using same template all over?

@KrishnaKanth yes this is the most efficient solution, else the function to create the createEmbeddedView will get called multiple times, but if you want like that let me know!

@KrishnaKanth the ngcomponentoutlet, does not have an input for template ref with context, so I am suggesting this solution, since there are less multiple calls and better performance!

createEmbeddedView  will be costlier here as we increase Items this should be fine. am wondering why should not we have option to pass an template ? to reduce that exta loop ?

@KrishnaKanth template can be pass as @Input maybe explore that option also!

Exaclty am trying to explore the same @Input Option let me see.
